# distributed FFT matrix solvers

Tags: matrices

i am working in a small project where i code a distributed matrix solver
where each matrix dots is represented by a function itself and the final computation
of each threaded solver is queued to the next matrix solver function calculator
similar to s-boxes but from a neat python software implementation.

- Help me out what mathematics research fields i am into
- How would those interconnected matrixed would be finally represented in an algebraic form?
- any ideas how to proced implementing both the solver and threaded?

the project aimst to apply small fast solvers to FFT F(q) byproducts so i can analyze several noise signals among frequency peaks.

Answer (score 0):

Some 30 years ago, the research area of [Systolic Arrays](https://www.google.de/search?q=fft%20array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb#newwindow=1&client=firefox-a&hs=KwR&hl=de&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&channel=fflb&sclient=psy-ab&q=fft%20%22systolic%20array%22&oq=fft%20%22systolic%20array%22&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.110947.111655.4.113215.4.4.0.0.0.0.81.279.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.PXOxQrFsmww&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.Yms&fp=9c322f40fae1e6b4&biw=1920&bih=972) gained a lot of attention: Rather simple processors in a regular mesh, cleverly connected to compute FFT, matrix multiplication and other numerical algorithms. The ideas might still be inspiring for you.

Another area to look for is [CUDA FFT](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=cuda%20fft). [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) is a programming model for PC graphics boards with massive parallelism of graphical CPUs (aka "GPU").

The basic Cooley–Tukey FFT algorithm is described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm).